# Replace strings in Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>> in ListView AfterLabelEdit event

Tags: c#, string, list, tuples

*Thanks to Peter Duniho's tip on how a Stack Overflow question has to look like, I converted my original question and its title hopefully to something more appropriate.*

---

So I'm currently working on a conversation editor for a chatbot which consists of a treeview and two listviews. I store each treenode as a key(int) in a dictionary. The dictionary structure looks like this:

> ```
> Dictionary<selectedNode(int), Tuple<List<listView1ItemLabels(string)>, List<listView2ItemLabels(string)>>>
> ```

Each list in the Tuple holds the labels of the items which are dynamically added to the two listviews at runtime using this custom function:

```
void AddItemToListView1(string itemName)
{
    // add new Item to listView1 and 
    dictionary[selectedNodeID].Item1.Add(itemName);
    // add its Text to the dictionary Tuple first generic list
    listView1.Items.Add(itemName);
}
```

When I click a node (or rather "the corresponding dictionary key"), both listviews will be repopulated from the lists in the Tuple via the AfterSelect event of the treeView, which looks like this:

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(string str in dictionary[selectedNodeID].Item1)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(str);
    }
    foreach(string str in dictionary[selectedNodeID].Item2)
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(str);
    }
}
```

**What I want to achieve is to change the string in the tuple's lists according to the change that happens to the listview item inside the AfterLabelEdit event. My approach below is obviously incorrect, even though the methods are valid:**

```
private void listView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Capture the yet unedited label of the item
    oldLabel = e.Label;
}

private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Label == null)
        return;

    if(e.Label == "")
        e.CancelEdit = true;

    // remove the selected listview item label, which was previously added using the custom AddItem() function
    dictionary[selectedNodeID].Item1.Add(e.Label);
    dictionary[selectedNodeID].Item1.Remove(oldLabel);

}
```

I really don't see any reason why this won't work. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Here's a picture of the GUI. May be it helps people understand what this is all about. :-)
[image]

Comment: Please post a concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the issue. Note that you are not asking about GUI code, so nothing in your example should have any GUI-related code. Note that you are asking about a specific scenario with a specific dictionary type and some specific operations, so your example definitely _should_ include a complete program that includes the declaration of the objects and statements which use them to demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: It looks like you are removing an item from an empty list.

Comment: And just FYI: the main reason the Tuple.Create() methods exist is to take advantage of type inference to make the code simpler. Where you write "Tuple.Create<List<string>, List<string>>(tempItems1, tempItems2)", you could just write "Tuple.Create(tempItems1, tempItems2)"

Comment: @Peter Duniho Thanks for the hint and sorry, I was on a rush when I created the question. I'll edit it as soon as I am back at home.

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by "won't work"? What's the behavior you're seeing? When you're stepping through the code with a debugger and watching what happens, at what point does it end up in a state not consistent with what you were going for?